# How can I render one JS ERB template from another JS ERB template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I don't know if I'm doing this right. I have a standard `common/flashes.js.erb` template that I render after certain Ajax actions. Yet in one instance I want to update a table on the screen also. So I end up needing to render two different templates. I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
alert("done");
<% render 'common/flashes' %>
```

just to test to see if the alert will run and the render the flashes. It doesn't.

Am I taking the wrong approach, or is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work and actually render the result of your ruby statement on the document:

```
<%= render 'common/flashes' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you rename the file to `common/_flashes.js.erb`? (prefixed with underscore)